# How to apply javascript function into multiple same name input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Please help i want to apply the javascript in the input list.
This is what i have right now. When i click the item in select list, the input textbox will be autofill and it is working right now but when i add input textbox using jquery, the javascript i used in select list is not applied on the new input. It apply only on the first select, the original list.
What should i do to apply it on all select list?
Click this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qfxtvrtu/) for the sample

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#category").change(function () {
        var unit = $(this).find(':selected').data('number');
        $('#numbervalue').val(unit);
    });

    var counter = 2;
    $("#addNumber").click(function () {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('tr')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDivMat' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<td><select id="category"><option data-number="1" value="One">One</option><option data-number="2" value="Two">Two</option><option data-number="3" value="Three">Three</option></select></td><td><input id="numbervalue" type="text"></td>');
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroupMat");
        counter++;
    });
    $("#removeButtonMat").click(function () {
        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDivMat" + counter).remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="TextBoxesGroupMat">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Number</th>                                        
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody id="TextBoxDivMat1"> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="category">                                       
                    <option data-number="1" value="One">One</option>
                    <option data-number="2" value="Two">Two</option>
                    <option data-number="3" value="Three">Three</option>
                </select>
            </td> 
            <td><input id="numbervalue" type="text"></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>        
</table>
<button id="addNumber">+ add number</button>
<button id="removeButtonMat">remove</button>
```

Comment: There's a few things wrong with this - mainly IDs MUST be specific within a page, especially if you are looking at binding change handlers. Instead, give the selects a class, then look for the next input to add the value in to on select change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is that you're changing an ID, which then only changes the first ID input - change to classes and all is good - see below snippet:

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/qfxtvrtu/1/)

Also, it's a bad idea to have `on change` on a select if there is no blank option - a user must first select `two` to then go back and select `one`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).on("change", ".category", function () { /* changed to class */
    var unit = $(this).find(':selected').data('number');
    $(this).parent().next().find('.numbervalue').val(unit); /* ugly but works, could be better */
});

var counter = 2;
$("#addNumber").click(function () {
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('tr'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDivMat' + counter);
 
/* changed to add select and input with classes not IDs */ 
newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<td><select class="category"><option data-number="1" value="One">One</option><option data-number="2" value="Two">Two</option><option data-number="3" value="Three">Three</option></select></td><td><input class="numbervalue" type="text"></td>');
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroupMat");
counter++;
     });
$("#removeButtonMat").click(function () {
counter--;
 $("#TextBoxDivMat" + counter).remove();
 
     });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TextBoxesGroupMat">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Word</th>
                                        <th>Number</th>                                        
                                    </tr> 
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="TextBoxDivMat1"> 
         <tr>
                                    <td><select class="category">                                       
            <option data-number="1" value="One">One</option>
                                       <option data-number="2" value="Two">Two</option>
                                       <option data-number="3" value="Three">Three</option>
            </select></td> 
                                     <td><input class="numbervalue" type="text"></td> 
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>        
</table>

<button id="addNumber">+ add number</button>
<button id="removeButtonMat">remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Darren, its working. But when i attached bootstrap-selectpicker and apply it to select it gives me blank when i click addnumber button. Can you please take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qfxtvrtu/5/

Comment: Add this into your `$('#addNumber').click(){ .. }` - `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
            liveSearch: true,
            title: 'Choose Line'
        });` You have to call the plugin each time you add a new select

Comment: I added it but it is not showing on the first try. It will display after i clicking on the second click. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qfxtvrtu/6/

Comment: You have to add it AFTER you've added the select to the DOM - have a look at this, I simply moved it to the end of the function - https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/c2q838xv/

Comment: Got it. Thanks Darren! You are absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you add new elements into your HTML document then you need to attach the event to the newly added elements once again. After you add the new elements, you can call the function. But when you use ID then it is very likely that the jQuery will attach the function to the first element having that ID. If you want to use the same function to a bunch of elements then you can use a class identifier.

```
// Using ID
$("#category").on("change", function() {
// Your code here
})

// using class
$(".category").on("change", function() {
// your code here
})`
```

Comment: Look at the fiddle, this is not the issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jh5xoo7a/1/

I've added the counter to the id of the select and input elements to get the correct references. Possibly can use the parent --> next element method avoid attaching the counter to the id.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code

```
$(document).on('change',"#category",function () {
var unit = $(this).find(':selected').data('number');
$(this).parent().parent().find('#numbervalue').val(unit);
});
```

Comment: Again, just wrong - this is not the issue - look at the fiddle

Comment: Yes .I looked at that and checked with my code. It is working as he expected

Answer (score -1):

Replace categroy listener with

```
$(document).on('change', "#category",function () {
    var unit = $(this).find(':selected').data('number');
    $(this).parent().parent().find('#numbervalue').val(unit);
});
```

Comment: Look at the fiddle on the OP

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Unless I'm missing some second layer in the question, this seems to work just fine in the OP's fiddle. Even with the same ID, the delegated event will work on all selects and set `this` to the proper scope, and because the second ID is only searched for in a the defined scope, it works to set the textbox in the same row. Granted the OP should try to avoid using the same id, but it doesn't seem that the answer in itself is wrong.

Comment: @Me.Name - I get your point - I was trying to highlight that instead of showing a user the wrong way to make something right, maybe we should try to show them the errors of their ways from the get go. Will reverse the -1 - plus this is an exact copy of the answer above I've just noticed - never good